# Fresh response vs Cached response in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

With my recent development work, I need a way to determine whether the current response received is from  Cache or if the Server has sent a very fresh response. This is so because there are some javascript codes that needs to be executed for every fresh response & **NOT** every fresh user.

You all may agree that showing the Javascript code Which Will be executed on every fresh response won't add anything meaningfull to my question, since it's totally irrelevant and not connected with the way a server respose is sent.

So, Is there any way to differentiate whether the response is from the Cache or  is a new fresh copy sent by the server ??

Comment: please take sometime and re-form the question. a bit vague IMHO...

Comment: Naveen, PLease let me know what seems Vague? I will explain more

Answer (score 0):

You should consider creating a custom OutputCacheProvider that extends the built in cache provider used in MVC.

Some links that might help:

- MSDN Article: [Building and Using Custom OutputCache Providers in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg650661.aspx)
- [Creating a Custom Output Cache Provider in ASP.NET 4](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/creating-a-custom-output-cache-provider/232601001)
- [Custom Output Caching with MVC3 and .NET 4.0 – Done Properly!](http://www.haneycodes.net/custom-output-caching-with-mvc3-and-net-4-0-done-right/)

Within your provider, you can use the same functionality as the regular output cache provider. And on the `Get()` action, you can add content to the item returned from the cache that will indicate that it was in fact retrieved from cache (you will want to experiment with this, making sure that you are only adding this to the items that you want, and are doing it in a way that doesn't mess up the output).